# Div tags and alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, html

I have the following situation with my Div tags and floating them.  I have 3 sections of the page - header, body, footer. My issue is with the main(body) section.  Within that section I added two div tags to create a left and right area of the body section.  I floated the leftCol to the left.  But the rightCol is longer than the left so the rightcol text is going back under the leftCol div and I don't want that.  I want basically two cols created in that body section.  Here is the basic div structure of what I am doing below.

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="main">
   <div class="leftCol"></div>
   <div class="rightCol"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

How can I create two columns with div tags within that main one?

Comment: can you please include your css ?

Answer (score 2):

The width of both columns may be exceeding the with of the 'main' container. Remember, padding is included in the total width of each. Also, set the following float for both columns:

> float: left;

Answer (score 1):

Float both columns to the left.  This will cause both columns to show next to each other, in document order from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Float the right column left as well.  Make sure you specify a width on the floated elements.

If you want to make this easier on yourself, consider using blueprint or other CSS layout framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe a little late on this question but if you want table behaviour with div tags you can do as follow :

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="main" style="display:table-row">
   <div class="leftCol" style="display:table-cell"></div>
   <div class="rightCol" style="display:table-cell"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: delete the div declarations.
Step 2: use tables.
Step 3: Relax knowing that it just works.

I tend to use a mix of tables and divs depending on the situation.  If I have to have a 2 column layout and I want to ensure not only browser compatibility but also that various screen resolutions won't jack with the layout: I use tables.

If I'm okay with, or even desire, a column falling down to the next line because the width isn't available then I'll use a div.

What you have described, even the verbiage you used, is exactly what a table is for.  Tables have columns.  Floating stuff doesn't.

Comment: Tempted to +1 this just because it's funny.